# How to fix the one step delay for Atom text editor?

Tags: atom-editor, keymapping

I've been using Atom recently and loving it. There is one problem though. I'd like to move around the insertion point without leaving the home row. I set up my keymap to something as seen in the below picture.

[image]

I can move left and right without any problems, but when I try to go up or down, I need to press the key twice to put it in effect. There is one key delay, which is very very strange. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Are there perhaps existing mappings for `ctrl-j` and `ctrl-k` (or very similar mappings, like `ctrl-k a`)? If there's a conflict, it may be waiting for you to disambiguate which behavior you want.

Comment: @8bittree thanks for your suggestion, but I don't think conflict is the problem since ctrl-l is working. ctrl-l is for selecting a line by default, but I disabled it so that I can move to the right. I also disabled ctrl-k,j,h to avoid any conflicts, but there is still this weird delay persisting for ctrl-k and ctrl-j.

Comment: @8bittree you were right. There are many keybindings that start with ctrl-k, and that was causing problem. I changed all the keymap to ctrl-shift-j,k,h,l and it worked all fine, thanks!

Comment: @tet I'm having the exact same problem. Could you please tell me where you found the conflicting key bindings, so I can change them as well?

Comment: Found it under "Settings" -> "Keybindings"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for existing mappings for <kbd>ctrl-j</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl-k</kbd> (or very similar mappings, like <kbd>ctrl-k</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>). If there's a conflict, it may be waiting for you to disambiguate which behavior you want.